# /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so when searching for -lQtCore

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, build-error

When I try to build a new project using Qt Creator, I get these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so when searching for -lQtGui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtGui
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so when searching for -lQtCore
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtCore
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [untitled] Error 1
```

This is the command line from Compile Output:

```
g++ -m32 -o untitled main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
```

It seems it is trying to build in 32-bit mode even though I'm on Ubuntu 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem - my Qt Kits were all wrong. I had reinstalled Ubuntu recently, switching from 32-bit to 64-bit, but I had preserved my home folder, and I had a stale configuration at `~/.config/QtProject/`. Deleting that folder fixed my problem and now Qt Creator builds projects fine.